# org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering X from Y has the wrong number of column. should be 2

Tags: java, hibernate

Can anyone help me with this and tell me what I'm missing. Have gone through a number of examples and seem to have everything configured correctly but I keep getting this exception:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.bank.entity.Customer from com.bank.entity.Account has the wrong number of column. should be 2
```

I have a class called `Branch` that has 1:M relationship with `Customer`. `Customer` in turn has a 1:M relationship with `Account`.

Note: `Customer` also has an embeddable `Address` class

Here is my code:
**Branch Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Branch")
public class Branch extends AbstractPersistable<Long> implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "branch_Name")
private String branchName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "branch")
private Set<Customer> customers;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

**Embeddable Address Class**

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {
@Column(name = "houseNumber", nullable = false)
private String houseNumber;

@Column(name = "streetName", nullable = false)
private String streetName;

@Column(name = "city", nullable = false)
private String city;

@Column(name = "country", nullable = false)
private String country;

@Column(name = "eirCode", nullable = false)
private String eirCode;
}
```

**Customer Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customer")
public class Customer extends AbstractPersistable<Long> implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "first_Name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "surname")
private String surName;

@Embedded
Address address;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "branchId", nullable = false)
private Branch branch;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
private Set<Account> accounts;

}
```

**Account Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Account")
public class Account extends AbstractPersistable<Long> implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "account_type")
private String type;

@Column(name = "interest_rate")
private double rate;

@Column(name = "account_balance")
private double balance;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "customerId", nullable = false)
private Customer customer;
}
```

**Here I create the tables**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Branch` (
`id` BIGINT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`branch_Name` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Customer` (
`id` BIGINT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`first_Name` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
`surname` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
`houseNumber` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
`streetName` VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
`city` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
`country` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
`eirCode` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
`branchId` BIGINT(10)   NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `FK_CUST_BRANCH` (`branchId`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_CUST_BRANCH` FOREIGN KEY (`branchId`) REFERENCES `Branch`   (`id`)
 );

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Account` (
`id` BIGINT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`account_type` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
`interest_rate` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
`account_balance` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
`customerId` BIGINT(10)   NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `FK_CUST_ACC` (`customerId`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_CUST_ACC` FOREIGN KEY (`customerId`) REFERENCES `Customer` (`id`)
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Account` you are saying :

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "customerId", nullable = false)
private Customer customer;
```

But there is not column with name `customerId`(?) so you should give name to primary key of `Customer`

try changing this in `Customer`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customer")
public class Customer extends AbstractPersistable<Long> implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="customerId")
private Long id;

...
}
```

Comment: ...and if I am not wrong then same as for `Customer to Branch`